# Is it required to update the UI on the UI Thread in Swing?

Tags: java, android, swing, user-interface, thread-safety

In Android it causes HUGE issues if you don't put all of your UI changes on the UI Thread. Does it matter as much in Swing? I've never used recalled the UIThread before programming for Android. Are you suppose to do UI changes on the UI Thread in Swing?

Comment: You simply need to read about [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it is necessary to use the Event Thread (UI Thread) in Java when performing actions on the UI.

See: [The Event Dispatch Thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html)

Answer (score 3):

The Android UI toolkit is not thread-safe and must *always* be manipulated on the UI thread.

Android offers several ways to access the UI thread from other threads:

- [`Activity.runOnUiThread(Runnable)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread%28java.lang.Runnable%29)
- [`View.post(Runnable)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#post%28java.lang.Runnable%29)
- [`View.postDelayed(Runnable, long)`](http://tinyurl.com/bqx9ux2)
- [`Handler`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html)

The same is true with Swing. From the documentation,

> A note on thread safety: It may seem strange that such an important part of the Java platform is not thread safe. It turns out that any attempt to create a thread-safe GUI library faces some fundamental problems. For more on this issue, see the following entry in Graham Hamilton's blog: [MultiThreaded toolkits: A failed dream?](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/kgh/archive/2004/10/multithreaded_t.html)

Comment: yes i know that, my question was not about android, it was about Java

Comment: Java is a programming language... programming languages don't have "UI threads". Are you talking about swing?

Comment: @John, well I assume you do, so the answer is yes. See my updated post.

Comment: @John It depends on what you mean by get a hold of it, but you can work with the UI Thread (aka the Event Dispatch Thread, aka EDT, aka the Event Thread) by using the static [`SwingUtilities`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html) methods. In particular, you most likely want to look at `invokeLater`, `invokeAndWait`, and `isEventDispatchThread`.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, in most languages or user interfaces (iPhone, Android, etc.), the updating of the UI needs to be on the main thread or at least some secondary thread that controls access to the UI elements.

Comment: Euh, no, Swing must be updated on the Event Dispatch Thread, which is not the same as the main thread